# How do i make it so i don't have to query a million+ timestamps

Tags: mysql, time-series

Quick synopsis of the problem:

I am working on a graph page to map the performance of a device my company is working on.
I get a new statpoint (timestamp, stats, nodeid, volumeid, clusterid) every 2 seconds. from every node.

this results in approximately 43k records per day per node per stat.
now let's say i have 13 stats. that's 520k ish records a day.

So a row would look something like:

```
timestamp                typeid    clusterid    nodeid    volumeid    value
01/02/2016   05:02:22    0         1            1         1           82.20
```

So brief explanation, we decided to go with mysql because it's easily scaleable in Amazon. i was using Influx before which could easily solve this problem but there is no way to auto scale InfluxDB in Amazon.

My ultimate goal is to get a return value that looks like:

```
object[ {
    node1-stat1: 20.0,
    node2-stat1: 23.2,
    node3-stat1: xx.x,
    node1-stat2: 20.0
    node2-stat2: xx.x,
    node3-stat2: xx.x,
    timestamp: unixtimestamp
},
{
    node1-stat1: 20.0,
    node2-stat1: 23.2,
    node3-stat1: xx.x,
    node1-stat2: 20.0
    node2-stat2: xx.x,
    node3-stat2: xx.x,
    timestamp: unixtimestamp + 2 seconds
}]
```

i currently have a query that gathers all the unique timestamps.
and then loops over those to get the values belonging to that timestamp. 
and that get's put in an object.

That results in the desired output. but it takes FOREVER to do this and it's over a million queries.

Can something like this even be done in Mysql? should i go back to a timeseries db? and just deal with scaling it manually?

// EDIT //

I think i might have solved my problem:

```
SELECT data_points.*, data_types.friendly_name as friendly_name 
FROM data_points, data_types  
WHERE (cluster_id = '5' 
AND data_types.id = data_points.data_type_id
AND unix_timestamp(timestamp) BETWEEN '1456387200' AND '1457769599')         
ORDER BY timestamp, friendly_name, node_id, volume_id
```

Gives me all the fields i need.
I then loop over these datapoints. and create a new "object"  for each timestamp, and just add stats to this object for all the ones that match the timestamp.

this executes in under a second going over a million records.

I will for sure try to see if swapping to a Timeseries db will make an improvement in the future.

Comment: I'm with a team that develops Axibase Time Series Database. Give it a try. We already compress data quite efficiently http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/data-storage-tests/atsd-vs-mysql/, you can scale vertically for free, and lots of other useful features for your use case.

Comment: "there is no way to auto scale InfluxDB in Amazon" That's largely true, but why does that matter? 500k records per day is a trivial load for InfluxDB. If you provisioned a c4.2xlarge for the DB server your load could grow four orders of magnitude and the single InfluxDB server would still be at less than 50% utilization.

Comment: 500k a day would be for 1 node. i'm expecting 10's, 100's, 1000's within the next year or so.